# How to sort comma separated (or otherwise) text?

Tags: text-editing, sorting

Suppose I have the following text:

```
int z;
int a;
int c;
int g;
```

or the following text:

`z, a, c, g`

How can I sort them to:

```
int a;
int c;
int g;
int z;
```

and

```
a, c, g, z
```

respectively?

Answer (score 4):

Use `M-x sort-lines` for the first example. For the second example, change it into

```
z, a, c, g,
```

then use `M-x sort-regexp-fields <RET> ., <RET> \& <RET>`.

Comment: Note that `.,` is specific to this example, if you need more generic patterns for coma separated words, you can use `\s-?\w+,?`